# C preprocessor # and ## operators

Tags: c, concatenation, c-preprocessor

The [C99 standard document](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) has the following example in the section related to the ## preprocessing operator:

> In the following fragment:
>
> ```
> #define hash_hash # ## #
> #define mkstr(a) # a
> #define in_between(a) mkstr(a)
> #define join(c, d) in_between(c hash_hash d)
>
> char p[] = join(x, y); // equivalent to
>                        // char p[] = "x ## y";
> ```
>
> The expansion produces, at various
>   stages:
>
> ```
> join(x, y)
> in_between(x hash_hash y)
> in_between(x ## y)
> mkstr(x ## y)
> "x ## y"
> ```
>
> In other words, expanding hash_hash
>   produces a new token, consisting of
>   two adjacent sharp signs, but this new
>   token is not the ## operator.

I don't understand why the substitution of hash_hash produces ## and not "##" or "#""#". What role are the single hashes before and after the double hash playing?

Any responses greatly appreciated.

Comment: single hashes before and after ## are just chars, and ## (token) will make them into two chars ## (not into token). after applying a mkstr to them, they will be converted to string of "##"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `##` in `# ## #` acts like an escape sequence in this expression. It concatenates the leftmost and the rightmost `#` to finally produce the token `##`. Simply defining the macro as `##` would cause an error since the concatenation operator expects two operands.

Comment: How does it decide that `# ## #` means `##` and not `"##"` followed by a syntax error (because the remaining `#` does not have a right operand)? - Does `##` have precedence over `#`?

Comment: After this happens, why it doesn't cause undefined behaviour? Since "##" is not a valid preprocessing token.