# What does "##" do in C?

Tags: c, operators, c-preprocessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C preprocessor and concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation)
>   [C preprocessor # and ## operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595082/c-preprocessor-and-operators)

While searching through some C code of an OS that I develop with (on an embedded project,) I found the following defines statement:

```
#define concatn(s1, s2) s1 ## s2
```

I've never seen the "##" operator and after a bit of serious googling, I can't find any reference to it.  What's going on here?

I've searched through the OS source, and I can't find any reference to the string "##" being defined as some other form of C operator.  Is this standard C, or is this possibly/probably a feature of the compiler?

Comment: concatenate in the preprocessor

Comment: ["## Operator C" -> I'm Feeling Lucky](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref.doc/ilcrefer17.htm) You don't get to use that "I'm Feeling Lucky" button much, but it works fine here.

Comment: Well, I don't know what is up with my Google context, but Google tends to ignore special characters when I search.  Every search that I tried returned results to generic, C operator lists-- none of which contained the "##" operator.  In fact, I opened many of those pages and searched within the page-- didn't find this any where.

Comment: @H2CO3: The question you linked is not a precedent covering this one - it is much more about one technical detail than about the ## operator generally.

Comment: Yes, I read that question-- this is not a duplicate and, certainly, not an "exact" one.

Comment: @jpalecek this question asks fewer things than the one I linked - so it is a subset of the problem mentioned there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's part of the **preprocessor**, concatenation of tokens, and `concatn(x,y)` is replaced by `xy`.

Answer (score 4):

`##` is  the *token pasting operator* in C. It is used to concatenate two tokens.

Example:

```
#define PASTE(front, back) front ## back
```

then

```
PASTE(name, 1)
```

creates the token `name1`

Answer (score 3):

This is standard c preprocessor string concatenation operator

Answer (score 2):

It is used to concatenate two tokens (in this case s1 and s2). More details [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation). It is standard C preprocessing, so every standards compliant compiler should handle it.

For instance:

```
concatn(a_, b) = 1;
```

Will macro to:

```
a_b = 1;
```